# Get the latest taxonomy/category?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm designing a custom magazine theme, where categories are used for different sections, and I created a custom "edition" taxonomy.

The editor will create a new term in that taxonomy for each new edition published, i.e. the number of the issue.

How can I query the latest "edition", so I can combine it with each category and then publish only the posts that belong to the newest edition?

Something along the lines on:
    ?edition=34&cat=studies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest edition should always be the term in that taxonomy with the highest term_id, right? Query get_terms and find the latest edition, then use that term to build the rest of your query...

```
$edition = get_terms('edition','orderby=none&order=DESC&number=1');
$latest_edition = $edition[0]->slug;
```

Then you can either modify the current query, if that's what you want to do:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->set('edition',$latest_edition);
```

Or use it to build new queries:

```
$studiesposts = get_posts('category_name=Studies&edition='.$latest_edition);
```

If you have your permalink structure set up, it should also work to build urls for new links, like this:

```
http://yourdomain.com/edition/34/category/studies
```

Comment: That should be the case. Can you help me build that query? thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I added a few examples above. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the plugin [Query Multiple Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/).